# Не работает Babel

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babel

Пытаюсь собрать frontend, опыта нет вообще, поэтому не ругайте если что )
Использую TypeScript, JSX. подключил React. Собираю с помощью Webpack.

**build.js**

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var config = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, '/app/Account'),
    entry: './login.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'out')
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }]
    }
}
var compiler = webpack(config);
compiler.run(function (err, stats) {
    console.log(stats);
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "umd",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

При этом в браузере видим следующее:

[image: браузер]

То есть превращение в понятный браузеру код не произошел. Что я делаю не так?

На всякий случай ещё структура проекта, мало ли, что-то нитуда воткнул:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

`jsx`, это у `javascript`, но Вы используете `typescript` у которого `tsx` и для которого не нужно `babel` компилятора и `.babelrc`, за исключением тех случаев, когда Вы `generator` и `Symbol` хотите в `es5` скомпилировать.

поэтому все что Вам нужно, это установить и подключить `typescript-loader`.

p.s. хочу особо подчеркнуть, что `babel` и `.babelrc` не навредят если вы их оставите, а использовать не будите.

Answer (score 0):

Эх, а проблема то оказалась даже и не в Babel. Немного повозившись я начал запускать всё в ручном режиме через консоль. Очень помогла команда `webpack --display-error-details` (как оказалось при запуске build.js, ошибки почему то не выводились, что заставило меня думать, что всё в порядке).

Ну и там по мелочи, не хватило файлика пресета для babel, решается `npm install babel-preset-es2015`.

Ну и собственно причина всех страданий в файле tsx была ошибка. На скриншоте видно это. нужно было имя модуля в import указывать './welcome' вместо 'welcome', как это сделал я. Эх WebStorm, такую лажу проглядел... )